# release management with artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

i want to do release management with Jenkins but I'm confused. which artifactory should i use. Is there any opensource artifactory is there to do release management process through jenkins.I'm trying for the past month.

Comment: afaik out-of-the-box release management through Jenkins with Artifactory is only for maven or gradle builds -- not sure how to proceed with other toolchains.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source version of "Artifactory" which you could use (https://bintray.com/jfrog/product/JFrog-Artifactory-Oss/view). As an alternative you can check out Nexus from sonatype: https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss

If you don't want to install programs you can also go with a file based repository on a server. Whatever you like :)

Comment: I want to implement in my organization. Is open source safe or should i go for commercial one.

Comment: If you're ok with the limitations of the OSS version (check their homepage, there's a comparison matrix) I'd say you can use it. I mean it's open source. If you have concerns it might be the best to contact JFrog or Sonartype directly.

Comment: @Joschi what are your concerns with the OSS version? Security? Features? 

If it's security than I can tell you that in Artifactory OSS the security and vulnerabilities protection is the same as on the Pro. If it's features then this is a different topic and that is totally up to you and your company needs. As sandy mentioned, the best thing for you to do is just to install it and play with it a bit, use the community's assistance with any inquiry that you have and get to the right decision that will serve your company needs. 

Disclaimer, I work at JFrog

Comment: @Ariel: I have no concerns. Sandy is the one who wants to use it in the company. I just pointed out that I think it's ok to use it but if he has concerns in terms of using it he should contact you guys.

Comment: @Joschi sorry I confused the user names :)